# Error Could Not Create the JVM A fatal exception has occured while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, minecraft

**Hi I used the mcp (Minecraft coder pack) for creating mods in Minecraft However once I set up the workplace and I want to debug the app or simply run it these errors occur :**

[image: error]

After that error another pop up show me :

a
[image: error2]

And here's what's in the console :

```
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc
```

Answer (score 0):

It works here's how :

If you get an error saying the java virtual machine couldn't start:

Go to "Debug"
Debug configurations
Arguments
and remove the    -Xincgc
and debug your client